# How to create deep copy of an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] original = { 1, 2, 3 };
            int[] copy = new int[3];
            copy = original;
            copy[0] = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I change value of `copy` array, then value of `original` array is also changed. What is the easiest way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Since `original` is of type `int[]` you can put just `int[] copy = original.ToArray();`

Comment: Quickest way is `copy = original.Clone() as int[];`